# pacman loading map from file txt

Tags: java, dictionary

I have problem with loading map from txt file.
code compiles, but it doesn't display the walls and dots, any solutions ?

```
   public String getMap(int x, int y){
   String index = Mapa[y].substring(x, x+1);
   return index;
```

}

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(pacmanRightOne, pozX, pozY, this);

    for(int x=0; x<14; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<14; y++){
            if(getMap(x ,y ).equals("s")){
                g.drawImage(getWall(),x ,y , this);
            }
            if(getMap(x,y).equals("k")){
                 g.drawImage(getDot(),x ,y, this);
            }                 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: No txt file here? What have you tried? Your tiles are 1 Pixel in height and width?

Comment: Can't see you are reading a file here.

Comment: @Fildor http://wklej.org/id/1437327/

Comment: OK, seems alright. But it will not print the Images as you expect, because your draw them at (0,0), (0,1), and so forth Pixel positions. You might want to draw them at ( x_index * imageheight, y_index * imagewidth ) ...